# Test for value within array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am dynamically building an array of objects using a process that boils down to something like this:

```
//Objects  Array
var objects = [];

//Object Structure
var object1 =  {"id":"foobar_1", "metrics":90};
var object2 = {"id":"some other foobar",  "metrics":50};
objects[0] = object1;
objects[1] = object2;
```

(Let it be said for the record, that if you can think of a better way to dynamically nest data such that I can access it with `objects[i].id` I am also all ears!)

There's ultimately going to be more logic at play than what's above, but it's just not written yet. Suffice it to say that the "object1" and "object2" parts will actually be in an iterator.

Inside that iterator, I want to check for the presence of an ID before adding another object to the array. If, for example, I already have an object with the ID `"foobar_1"`, instead of pushing a new member to the array, I simply want to increment its `"metrics"` value.

If I wasn't dealing with an array of objects, I could use `inArray` to look for "foobar_1" (a jQuery utility). But that won't look into the object's values. The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Keep a separate simple array of just the IDs. So instead of only relying on the `objects` array, I simply check `inArray` (or plain JS equivalent) for a simple "objectIDs" array that is used only for this purpose.
2. Iterate through my existing data object and compare my `"foobar_1"` needle to each `objects[i].id` haystack

I feel that #1 is certainly more efficient, but I can't help wondering if I'm missing a function that would do the job for me. A #3, 4, or 5 option that I've missed! CPU consumption is somewhat important, but I'm also interested in functions that make the code less verbose whether they're more cycle-efficient or not.

Comment: Why don't you make a big hash out of it (instead of array)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The honest truth is that I've never had occasion to use a hash, so I have zero knowledge in theory, best practices, or syntax. I don't mind breaking my comfort zone, but I'll have to teach myself. ;-)

Comment: See answer by @jfriend00. That's what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest switching to an object instead of an array:

```
var objects = {};
objects["foobar_1"] = {metrics: 90};
objects["some other foobar"] = {metrics: 50};
```

Then, to add a new object uniquely, you would do this:

```
function addObject(id, metricsNum) {
    if (!(id in objects)) {
        objects[id] = {metrics: metricsNum};
    } 
}
```

To iterate all the objects, you would do this:

```
for (var id in objects) {
    // process objects[id]
}
```

This gives you very efficient lookup for whether a given id is already in your list or not.  The only thing it doesn't give you that the array gave you before is a specific order of objects because the keys of an object don't have any specific order.

Comment: This makes good sense to me; it's what I originally imagined but the practical side (the `addObject` function specifically) was holding me up. I sometimes find it difficult to match practical code and syntax with ideas in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm , i wonder why dont you use dictionary cause that is perfectlly fits your case. so your code will be as below:

```
//Objects  Array
var objects = [];

//Object Structure
var object1 =  {"metrics":90};
var object2 = {"metrics":50};
objects["foobar_1"] = object1;
objects["some other foobar"] = object2;

// An example to showing the object existence.
if (!objects["new id"]){
    objects["new id"] = {"metrics": 100};
}
else {
    objects["new id"].matrics++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Moutasem. Looks similar to jfriend00's; where his is an object, period, you seem to be sticking to the original "array of objects" description. Other than that, functionally equivalent.

Comment: One has to be careful with statements like `if (!objects["new id"])`.  If the id could ever be 0 (or any falsey value), then this would not work properly.

Comment: Why do you declare objects as an array and then use it like an object?